# Nested foreach loops java

Tags: java, foreach

```
for (Comment mc : relevant) {
    for (GitItem gi : tree) {
      bb.buildBody(gi.getHash(), mc.getBody());
      MutableComment mutable = commentManager.getMutableComment(mc.getId());
      mutable.setBody(bb.sb.toString());
      commentManager.update(mutable, true);
    }
}
```

So I've made this nested foreach loop with the hopes that I'll add the 1st item from `tree`(which is a TreeSet of GitItems) to the first comment from `relevant` (which is a List of Comments whose size is equal to the size of `tree`) and so on (In this example I have 2 comments and 2 items). But what it does right now is, that it adds only the 2nd item from tree to each of the two comments. What am I doing wrong?

Comment: Seems a bit too localized

Comment: You should initialize `bb` inside loop. Same reference is getting updated.

Comment: Currently you'd be trying to update *every* `GitItem` with *every* `Comment`... as well as Amit's point.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your inner loop iterates always over *all* the items in tree, so the body is set to the last tree item for all comments. If I understood you right, what you want is stepping the iterators in sync (in pseudocode, since I don't know what your `relevant` and `tree` etc are:

```
Iterator<Comment> commentIter = relevant.iterator();
Iterator<GitItem> itemIter = tree.iterator();
while (commentIter.hasNext() && itemIter.hasNext()) {
    Comment mc = commentIter.next();
    GitItem gi = itemIter.next();

    bb.buildBody(gi.getHash(), mc.getBody());
    MutableComment mutable = commentManager.getMutableComment(mc.getId());
    mutable.setBody(bb.sb.toString());
    commentManager.update(mutable, true);
}
```

Comment: If `relevant` and `tree` can be accessed by index, then take a look at Duncan Jones' solution which is the essentially same thing but uses indices. That can be more readable.

Comment: With this it adds the 1st item from tree to both comments.

Comment: Either I'm blind today, or the iterator loops are correct, and should properly iterate the tree too. Are you sure the other parts of the code correct?

Comment: That's what I'm testing right now, I can't find any error in your code either, but from what I can see, this should be the right answer.

Comment: You're welcome, it's nice to be of help. Good that you found the problem.